# Display a data table in WinForms

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm creating a Windows form that displays a data table. I would also like to be able to select a row from the displayed table and have the information displayed on the form that called it. I've connected to the server but can't seem to populate the data table.

```
Dim Students As String = "select * from dbo.[students]"
Dim Studentscmd As New SqlCommand(Students, cnn)
Dim Studentstable As New DataTable
Dim Studentadapter As New SqlDataAdapter

Dim NStudents As DataSet = New DataSet()
Studentadapter.Fill(NStudents)

Datagridview.DataGridView1.DataSource = NStudents
Datagridview.DataGridView1.Show()
```

Comment: You have no linkage between your DataAdapter and Your Command or Connection that I can see. Basically your defining a new Adapter and passing it an empty DataSet. Look at the example in MSDN for how your supposed to do this.

Comment: Your missing `StudentAdapter.SelectCommand = StudentsCmd` before the FILL command

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
(As @DarrenMB mentioned you missing linkage between `SqlAdapter` and `SqlCommand`)

```
Dim Students As String = "select * from dbo.[students]"
Dim Studentstable As New DataTable()
Using Studentscmd As New SqlCommand(Students, cnn)
    Using Studentadapter As New SqlDataAdapter(Studentscmd) 'This link Adapter with command
        Studentadapter.Fill(Studentstable) 'Can fill straight to DataTable
    End Using
End Using
Datagridview.DataGridView1.DataSource = Studentstable
Datagridview.DataGridView1.Show()
```

"Better practice" to use a [Using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) when deal with unmanaged resources like database
On the `End Using` all objects and resources created with `Using` will be disposed/released properly